# WPF DataGrid display 'NULL' when bound property is null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to display a cell containing a 'NULL' string instead of a blank cell when the corresponding source value is null. I'm using a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataTable` and `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`.

Previously I managed to do it in the code-behind through the AutoGeneratedColumns event, but now I've switched to MVVM design and I wanted to avoid this.

```
foreach (var column in dgwCustomTableSelected.Columns)
{
    if (column is DataGridTextColumn) 
    {
        ((DataGridTextColumn)column).Binding = 
            new Binding() { 
                Converter = new NullValueConverter((string)column.Header) 
            };
    }
}
```

I was wondering whether there's a way to associate a Converter to all the datagrid columns or any other feasible solution to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: mvvm != no codebehind.  Specifically, view-related code should exist within the view. Lots of new mvvm devs think everything has to come out, and often make the mistake of putting UI related code in their view models.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering whether there's a way to associate a Converter to all the datagrid columns or any other feasible solution to this.

The "feasible solution" would be to handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event in the view. Or define all columns explicitly in the XAML markup of the same view.

Neither approach breaks the MVVM pattern since this is view-related functionality and MVVM is *not* about eliminating view-related code from the views. It is mainly about separation of concerns and doing *view-related* things programmatically instead of doing it in the XAML markup is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you @mm8, I can hire you as a personal consultant if you take your breaks where you get 'em :) Define all columns is not possible because I use this approach in order to map the DataGrid to any kind of resultset returned from my server side. So I don't know which column I have to deal with in advance. I will continue to use code behind for this.. As you said not all code-behind breaks MVVM pattern. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it in the `ViewModel`. Lets say your `ViewModel` class would look something like this (I left INotofyPropertyChanged out for simplicity):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ModelClass model = new ModelClass();

    public string Name
    {
       get
       {
           return model.Name;
       }
       set
       {
           model.name = value;
       }
    }
}
```

You could refactor it to something like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ModelClass model = new ModelClass();

    public string Name
    {
       get
       {
           if(model.Name == null)
           {
              return "NULL";
           }

           return model.Name;
       }
       set
       {
           model.name = value;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Romano for helping me out. Well, in my ViewModel I directly expose a DataTable to which the DataGrid is bounded. I let the DataGrid to autogenerate it's columns based on the DataTable  content

Comment: @gipinani Where do you get that `DataTable` from? Could you replace the `string` before populating the `DataTable`

Comment: I'm getting the DataTable from a WCF service. Well, I would continue to provide the DataModel as is to the DataGrid. Replacing the string before filling the DataGrid probably would mean loop through all the rows / columns and replace the values (if I've well understood). And honestly it seems a bit overkilling

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `Custom Markup Extension` that will allow you to include `Converter` inside of the `Binding`. For that to work you would also have to create `DataTemplates` for different types of data but overall gain, namely handling the data types, would outweigh the amount of coding. Here is an example of said Markup Extension from [searchwindevelopment](http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/Simplify-your-Binding-Converter-with-a-Custom-Markup-Extension)

```
class NumberToBrushConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    private static NumberToBrushConverter _converter = null;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // determine if we have an instance of converter
        // return converter to client
        return _converter ?? (_converter = new NumberToBrushConverter());
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                      object parameter,CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

  }
```

Then in xaml you would use it like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ValueConverterTips.CustomMarkupTip"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters='clr-namespace:ValueConverterTips.Converters'
    Title="CustomMarkupTip" >

    <!-- no longer need the resources section -->

    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Fill='{Binding SomeIntData,  
         Converter={converters:NumberToBrushConverter}}'
         Width='10' Height='10' />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You would have to modify this to suit your scenario.
**EDIT**
This is how you would use this with `AutoGenerateColumns=true`:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Button Content="Ok"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>

<DataGrid AutGenerateColumns="true" ItemsSource={Binding xxx} etc...>

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: How does this apply to auto-generated DataGrid columns and the actual question?

Comment: @mm8 I refer you to "_I was wondering whether there's a way to associate a Converter to all the datagrid columns or any other feasible solution to this._" with additional emphasis on Any other feasible solution.

Comment: The problem is that the columns are *not* defined in XAML but auto-generated.

Comment: Yes @XAMlMAX, as mm8 said I don't know anything about the column I'm going to render.. that's why I can't have a static column definition

Comment: @mm8 I hope this makes more sense? If part of the answer was from SO post which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26145155/2029607), which is very similar to this quesiton.